# Simplicity or Complexity, which is more important in speech and writing?

Tags: writing-style, speech

English or any other language could be written or spoken in both the forms, either the user could use simple words or he could use some technical words, my question regarding English is which has more impact on listener, Simplicity in language? or Complexity by using technical words? and is it dependent of whether you are speaking or writing?

Simplicity, i.e, using simple words in your language can be effective as it helps the listener understand you better. The brain of listener can easily understand what you meant to say, whereas Complexity brings elegance. A speech or text with some technical words used in it looks more promising and can express much more than the same text written in a simple language. So ultimately, which is better?

**PS** : By Complexity, I didn't meant to say English which could not be understood, I just meant the use of more complicated and technical words in the language.

Comment: This question may be too broad/opinion based...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no difference between English and any other language in this regard.

Comment: You might find more receptive audiences at [linguistics.se] or [writers.se].

Comment: I thought since it had an specific answer like a Yes/No question and deals with the usage of language, it would fit the criteria of this site. Extremely sorry for not comprehensively reading rules and checking that there exists Linguistic and Writers.

Answer (score 1):

I find that in both speaking and writing, it is much more impressive when one uses the technical terms you mentioned, as they are generally more accurate.  Most native English speakers  understand these more "complex" words, but do not necessarily use them in their day to day speech.  There are many words you can use that will make you sound well educated, while still being comprehensible to an average person.  Even if your listener cannot understand one or two of the words you used, you generally gain more precision than you lose understandability.